# Excel VBA, Get the value of a private worksheet constant

Tags: vba, excel

I want to retrieve the value of a worksheet-code-level private constant via VBA. I'm trying to do something similar to having "tags" on my worksheets that are accessible via VBA. I'd like to use the CodeModule in the VBAProject so that I can have a number of "tags", not just one. I just can't figure out how to grab the constant, even after reviewing much code and forums on-line. Does anyone have any insight on this? I am running Excel 2013 on a Windows 8.1 machine.

Comment: Does it *need* to be a Private constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the easiest way to do this is to have a function that can the value of a private constant with a public accessor method. For instance, if you have the following code in your worksheet `Sheet1`:

```
Private Const myValue = "the answer is 42"

Public Function getSecret()
  getSecret = myValue
End Function
```

Then you can access it from another module with

```
Sub test()
    Dim sheetName = "Sheet1"
    MsgBox "The sheet says that " & Sheets(sheetName).getSecret()
End Sub
```

You can make this fancier - you could create a collection of tags and index them… but I think that goes beyond the question you had. Note that you have to "fully qualify" the name of the accessor macro when it is in a worksheet; the advantage is that you can use the same function to examine the tag of different worksheets just by changing the `sheetName`.

Comment: Thanks, Floris!  Works like a charm!  I am curious about creating a collection of tags and indexing them.  If you have the time and could post about that, that would be great!  If not, that's OK, too.  I'm very happy to have the solution to the problem you provided.  Thanks!

Comment: Floris, In incorporating this into my code, I have discovered a "wrinkle."  In this code:  `For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        shtName = sht.Name
        On Error Resume Next
        shtType = sht.GetShtType()
        If Err.Number = 0 Then`, I get a Method or Data Member Not Found error on the .GetShtType() line.  Any suggestions?  I would like to be able to check for the sheet type condition.  Or do I need every sheet to have a type?  Please advise.

Comment: @user3525243 Glad the idea works for you. As for the error you see: that is strange - I would have thought that your `On Error` should prevent the error from showing up (other than in the `Err.Number` variable). Maybe you can post a new question about this with a link here - hard to work from code in comments. You realize you need this code in every worksheet, right?

Comment: I found a workaround.  I think that the code didn't like the declaration because I didn't have the .GetShtType() code in all sheets.  I didn't want the code in all sheets, though, just the ones for which I wanted to assign a type.  The workaround was to change the "shtType" line of code to `shtType = wb.Sheets(shtName).GetShtType()` where wb is the workbook in question and shtName is the name of the sheet being inspected.  This does work, and works quite well, just a little "cumbersome."

Brian

Answer (score 0):

I would export the code to a .BAS file.  You can then read the material back in as a text file and retrieve the constant